# Why does WKWebView crash when simulating on pre iOS 14?

Tags: swift, xcode

When simulating pre iOS 14 apps with WKWebView they crash with no console or stack info. Same code works on x86. Error occurs between `awakeFromNib` and `viewDidLoad` on initial view controller. Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: File a bug with Apple (though at this very early stage this may be expected behavior, for all one knows).

Comment: Thanks to a Twitter post by Peter Steinberger @steipete:

Testing iOS below 14 is a major problem. It seems WebKit is crashing in a memory allocator, throwing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) (Apple folks: FB8920323).